# How can I place certain pieces on a 5x5 chess board without any of them attacking each other?

Tags: puzzles

How can I place one queen, two bishops, two knights, and two rooks, on a 5×5 chessboard without any of them attacking other pieces?

After placing just queen and rooks, I can't make room for the other four pieces.

Comment: It would be nice to include a reference to the source of this problem.

Comment: I suppose the key is to realize the bishops can be placed on the same color as each other, since the puzzle doesn't specify otherwise.

Comment: @Stef It was a task at my college for practice.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson There are no restrictions, except they can't attack other pieces.

Comment: @JosipMaričević So you should try to do it - **for practice**.  You won't learn anything by giving your difficult work to other people to solve for you.

Comment: @J... I actually did it by myself, before I got an answer here.
I think the **practice** is the wrong word for it.

Comment: The constraints applicable to this problem are rather interesting. The queen and each rook control one rank and one file, meaning that three ranks and three files are totally controlled by those three pieces alone. This leaves only two ranks and two files for the other four pieces to inhabit - which is exactly enough space!

Comment: @Kevin: True. In every solution, bishops and knights are placed on a rectangle, on opposite corners.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I used [`chessboard`](https://github.com/kdeldycke/chessboard), a Python "CLI to solve combinatoric chess puzzles".

`chessboard solve --length=5 --height=5 --queen=1 --bishop=2 --rook=2 --knight=2`

outputs 24 boards, corresponding to 3 unique solutions, rotated or mirrored.

The queen must be on the edge of the board, but it can be anywhere along those edges (16 squares). There are 2 possible solutions if the queen is in the corner or in the middle square along the edge, for a total of 24 solutions.

Here's the output:

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ ♛ │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♜ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♝ │   │   │ ♞ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♞ │   │   │ ♝ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ ♛ │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♝ │ ♞ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │ ♜ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♜ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♞ │ ♝ │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │ ♛ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♝ │ ♞ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♜ │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♞ │ ♝ │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │ ♛ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♜ │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♜ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♝ │   │   │ ♞ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♞ │   │   │ ♝ │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │ ♛ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │ ♜ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♜ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♞ │   │   │ ♝ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♝ │   │   │ ♞ │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │   │ ♛ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♞ │ ♝ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │ ♜ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♝ │ ♞ │   │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │   │   │ ♛ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♜ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♞ │   │   │ ♝ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♝ │   │   │ ♞ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │   │   │ ♛ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♞ │ ♝ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♜ │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♜ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♝ │ ♞ │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♛ │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♜ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♝ │   │   │ ♞ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♞ │   │   │ ♝ │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │ ♛ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♜ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♞ │   │   │ ♝ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♝ │   │   │ ♞ │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │ ♜ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♝ │ ♞ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♛ │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♞ │ ♝ │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │   │ ♞ │ ♝ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♛ │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♝ │ ♞ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♜ │   │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │   │ ♜ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♞ │ ♝ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │ ♛ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♝ │ ♞ │   │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ ♝ │ ♞ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │ ♛ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♞ │ ♝ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♜ │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │ ♞ │   │   │ ♝ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♝ │   │   │ ♞ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♜ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♛ │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ ♝ │   │   │ ♞ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♞ │   │   │ ♝ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♜ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │ ♛ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♞ │   │   │ ♝ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♝ │   │   │ ♞ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♜ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♛ │   │   │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │ ♞ │ ♝ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♜ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │ ♜ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♝ │ ♞ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♛ │   │   │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │   │ ♞ │ ♝ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♜ │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♝ │ ♞ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♛ │   │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ ♝ │   │   │ ♞ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♞ │   │   │ ♝ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♜ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │ ♜ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♛ │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │ ♞ │   │   │ ♝ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♝ │   │   │ ♞ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♜ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♜ │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♛ │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ ♝ │ ♞ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │ ♜ │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♞ │ ♝ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♛ │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │ ♜ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♝ │   │   │ ♞ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♞ │   │   │ ♝ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♜ │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │ ♛ │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │ ♝ │ ♞ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │ ♜ │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ ♜ │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │ ♞ │ ♝ │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │ ♛ │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

Comment: So the different unique solutions (if we count symmetries) are only 3. Interesting

Comment: Unicode for the win!

Comment: I rolled back the last edit; it seems to depend on OS / browser / other settings [which version](https://chess.stackexchange.com/posts/39476/revisions) works better. For me (macOS, Safari/Firefox), revision 1 is correct.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Qa3, Rb1, Rc4, Bd2, Nd5, Ne2, Be5]

Qa3, Rb1, Rc4, Bd2, Nd5, Ne2, Be5

Answer (score 9):

Another solution (not clearly equivalent to Glorfindel's)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Generated 12 positions using python-chess. Here are the links from lichess.

- https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/2Q5/R7/3R4/1B2N3/1N2B3_w_-_-
- https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/1BN5/3R4/R7/1NB5/4Q3_w_-_-
- https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/2R5/Q7/3R4/1B2N3/1N2B3_w_-_-
- https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/2R5/1N2B3/1B2N3/3R4/Q7_w_-_-
- https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/Q7/2BN4/4R3/1R6/2NB4_w_-_-
- https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/4Q3/1NB5/R7/3R4/1BN5_w_-_-
- https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/4Q3/1R6/N2B4/B2N4/2R5_w_-_-
- https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/1Q6/3BN3/R7/2R5/3NB3_w_-_-
- https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/2Q5/4R3/1R6/N2B4/B2N4_w_-_-
- https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/3NB3/2R5/R7/3BN3/1Q6_w_-_-
- https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/3R4/NB6/4Q3/2R5/BN6_w_-_-
- https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/2NB4/1R6/4R3/2BN4/Q7_w_-_-